# Esconder div com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou tentando esconder uma `div` com o JavaScript.

Só que os botões não estão ativando nada e só estão escondendo tudo. Aliás, não está nem mesmo ativando a interatividade dos botões.

A ideia principal é que quando clicar a letra `A` aparece a tabela A, escondendo as demais. E quando clicar na letra `B`, esconde a `A`.

Exemplo abaixo (código completo em https://jsfiddle.net/Larck6/3vpmnx2r/1/):

```js
var div1;
var div2;

window.onload = function(){

  div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
  div2 = document.getElementById("div2");

  var bt1 = document.getElementById("bt1");
  bt1.onclick = mostrarDiv1;
  var bt2 = document.getElementById("bt2");
  bt2.onclick = mostrarDiv2;

  div1.classList.add ("escondido");
  div2.classList.add ("escondido");


}

function mostrarDiv1(){

  div1.classList.remove("escondido");
  div1.classList.add("escondido");

}

function mostrarDiv2(){
  div1.classList.add("escondido");
  div1.classList.remove("escondido");

}
```

```css
.escondido{
  display:none;
}

.botao{
  height:auto;
  width:100%;
  float: left;
  text-align:center;
  margin-top:15%;
  color: #c40027;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<div class="fundo">

<div class="cabecalho">

  <div class="logo"><img src="img/Logo%20Preta%20RCM.png"/></div>
  <div class="titulo">ESTOQUE BOBINAS</div>
  <div class="logo2"> <img src="img/png%20logo%20vermelha.png"></div>

</div>
<!-- >>>>>>>>> botao <<<<<<<<< -->
<div class="botao">
<button id="bt1"> A </button>
<button id="bt2"> B </button>
<button id="bt3"> C </button>
<button id="bt4"> E </button>
<button id="bt5"> F </button>
<button id="bt6"> G </button>
<button id="bt7"> H </button>
<button id="bt8"> I </button>
<button id="bt9"> J </button>
<button id="bt10"> Z </button> 
</div>
<!-- >>>>>>> FIM botao <<<<< -->



<div id="div1">

<!-- >>>>Tabela completa A<<<<  -->

<div class="pratileira_a"><h3>Prateileira A</h3></div>

<div class="parte1">

<div class="partileiraandar"> 

  <div class="andar">Andares</div>
  <div class="andar_p">Andar 0</div>
  <div class="andar_p">Andar 1</div>
  <div class="andar_p">Andar 2</div>
  <div class="andar_p">Andar 3</div>

</div>
 <!-- FIM  1 a 8 da -->
<div class="abc_dados_prateleiras">
  <div class="p_l">1</div>
  <div class="p_l">2</div>
  <div class="p_l">3</div>
  <div class="p_l">4</div>
  <div class="p_l">5</div>
  <div class="p_l">6</div>
  <div class="p_l">7</div>
  <div class="p_l">8</div>
 </div> 
 <!-- FIM  1 a 8 da -->


<!-- >>>>>>>>>>> inicio dos dados <<<<<<<<<< -->
<div class="dados_pratileira_1">
  <div id="andar0_1">256 aqui tem um texto muito grande</div>
  <div id="andar0_2">265</div>
  <div id="andar0_3">285</div>
  <div id="andar0_4">256</div>
  <div id="andar0_5">259</div>
  <div id="andar0_6">285</div>
  <div id="andar0_7">259</div>
  <div id="andar0_8">285</div>

  <!-- andar 1 -->
  <div id="andar1_1">256 aqui tem um texto muito grande</div>
  <div id="andar1_2">265</div>
  <div id="andar1_3">285</div>
  <div id="andar1_4">256</div>
  <div id="andar1_5">259</div>
  <div id="andar1_6">285</div>
  <div id="andar1_7">259</div>
  <div id="andar1_8">285</div>


  <!-- andar 2 --> 
  <div id="andar2_1">256 aqui tem um texto muito grande</div>
  <div id="andar2_2">265</div>
  <div id="andar2_3">285</div>
  <div id="andar2_4">256</div>
  <div id="andar2_5">259</div>
  <div id="andar2_6">285</div>
  <div id="andar2_7">259</div>
  <div id="andar2_8">285</div>


  <!-- andar 3 -->
  <div id="andar3_1">256 aqui tem um texto muito grande</div>
  <div id="andar3_2">265</div>
  <div id="andar3_3">285</div>
  <div id="andar3_4">256</div>
  <div id="andar3_5">259</div>
  <div id="andar3_6">285</div>
  <div id="andar3_7">259</div>
  <div id="andar3_8">285</div>

  <!-- >>>>>>>>>>> FIM dos dados <<<<<<<<<< -->

</div> 

</div> 

<!-- >>>> FIM Tabela completa A <<<<  -->

</div> <!-- >>>> FIM da DIV1 do botao 1 <<<<  -->



<div id="div2">

  <h1> TESTE </h1>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, Larck.
Pelo comportamento que entendi, seu código estava quase correto. Verifique se é este comportamento que você quer conforme o código abaixo. Apenas duas pequenas alterações foram feitas e estão comentadas.

Eu recomendaria criar métodos que você escondesse todas as `divs` e um método que receba como parâmetro o `Id` da `div` que deve aparecer, daí ela esconde todas e mostrar essa que recebeu por parâmetro, dessa forma você não vai precisar ficar criando método pra cada `div` e reescrevendo código.

```js
var div1;
var div2;

window.onload = function(){

  div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
  div2 = document.getElementById("div2");

  var bt1 = document.getElementById("bt1");
  bt1.onclick = mostrarDiv1;
  var bt2 = document.getElementById("bt2");
  bt2.onclick = mostrarDiv2;

  div1.classList.add ("escondido");
  div2.classList.add ("escondido");


}

function mostrarDiv1(){

  div1.classList.remove("escondido");
  div2.classList.add("escondido"); //mudei de div1 para div2

}

function mostrarDiv2(){
  div1.classList.add("escondido");
  div2.classList.remove("escondido"); //mudei de div1 para div2

}
```

```css
.escondido{
  display:none;
}

.botao{
  height:auto;
  width:100%;
  float: left;
  text-align:center;
  margin-top:15%;
  color: #c40027;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<div class="fundo">

<div class="cabecalho">

  <div class="logo"><img src="img/Logo%20Preta%20RCM.png"/></div>
  <div class="titulo">ESTOQUE BOBINAS</div>
  <div class="logo2"> <img src="img/png%20logo%20vermelha.png"></div>

</div>
<!-- >>>>>>>>> botao <<<<<<<<< -->
<div class="botao">
<button id="bt1"> A </button>
<button id="bt2"> B </button>
<button id="bt3"> C </button>
<button id="bt4"> E </button>
<button id="bt5"> F </button>
<button id="bt6"> G </button>
<button id="bt7"> H </button>
<button id="bt8"> I </button>
<button id="bt9"> J </button>
<button id="bt10"> Z </button> 
</div>
<!-- >>>>>>> FIM botao <<<<< -->



<div id="div1">

<!-- >>>>Tabela completa A<<<<  -->

<div class="pratileira_a"><h3>Prateileira A</h3></div>

<div class="parte1">

<div class="partileiraandar"> 

  <div class="andar">Andares</div>
  <div class="andar_p">Andar 0</div>
  <div class="andar_p">Andar 1</div>
  <div class="andar_p">Andar 2</div>
  <div class="andar_p">Andar 3</div>

</div>
 <!-- FIM  1 a 8 da -->
<div class="abc_dados_prateleiras">
  <div class="p_l">1</div>
  <div class="p_l">2</div>
  <div class="p_l">3</div>
  <div class="p_l">4</div>
  <div class="p_l">5</div>
  <div class="p_l">6</div>
  <div class="p_l">7</div>
  <div class="p_l">8</div>
 </div> 
 <!-- FIM  1 a 8 da -->


<!-- >>>>>>>>>>> inicio dos dados <<<<<<<<<< -->
<div class="dados_pratileira_1">
  <div id="andar0_1">256 aqui tem um texto muito grande</div>
  <div id="andar0_2">265</div>
  <div id="andar0_3">285</div>
  <div id="andar0_4">256</div>
  <div id="andar0_5">259</div>
  <div id="andar0_6">285</div>
  <div id="andar0_7">259</div>
  <div id="andar0_8">285</div>

  <!-- andar 1 -->
  <div id="andar1_1">256 aqui tem um texto muito grande</div>
  <div id="andar1_2">265</div>
  <div id="andar1_3">285</div>
  <div id="andar1_4">256</div>
  <div id="andar1_5">259</div>
  <div id="andar1_6">285</div>
  <div id="andar1_7">259</div>
  <div id="andar1_8">285</div>


  <!-- andar 2 --> 
  <div id="andar2_1">256 aqui tem um texto muito grande</div>
  <div id="andar2_2">265</div>
  <div id="andar2_3">285</div>
  <div id="andar2_4">256</div>
  <div id="andar2_5">259</div>
  <div id="andar2_6">285</div>
  <div id="andar2_7">259</div>
  <div id="andar2_8">285</div>


  <!-- andar 3 -->
  <div id="andar3_1">256 aqui tem um texto muito grande</div>
  <div id="andar3_2">265</div>
  <div id="andar3_3">285</div>
  <div id="andar3_4">256</div>
  <div id="andar3_5">259</div>
  <div id="andar3_6">285</div>
  <div id="andar3_7">259</div>
  <div id="andar3_8">285</div>

  <!-- >>>>>>>>>>> FIM dos dados <<<<<<<<<< -->

</div> 

</div> 

<!-- >>>> FIM Tabela completa A <<<<  -->

</div> <!-- >>>> FIM da DIV1 do botao 1 <<<<  -->



<div id="div2">

  <h1> TESTE </h1>

</div>
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Vlw, sera q teria como dar refresh somente na tabela q o botão for pressionado ?  Tentei alguns modos mas ele esta dando refresh na pagina toda.